# Is it possible to create a Unique (Index) constraint across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique-constraint

Is there a way to create a unique index across tables in a MySQL database?

By unique, I mean,

```
                table A ids=1,2,5,7... 

                table B ids=3,4,6,8...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this constraint (a "distributed key") is impossible to model as a standard SQL relational constraint. It can be simulated in several ways, but I have various approaches generally "icky" - although I sometimes still keep trying! - and do my best to avoid this sort of situation these days. I suggest trying to represent the the model in a more "SQL friendly" manner, if at all possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*I think*, it is not possible by directly creating a constraint. But there are some solutions in order for you to get unique IDs.

One suggestion would be is by using `TRIGGER`. Create a *BEFORE INSERT* trigger on both tables which checks the ID for existence during `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Second, is by creating a third table which contains `UNIQUE` numbers and the other tables: `TableA` and `TableB` will then be reference on the third one.

Answer (score 1):

Like JW says, this would probably work well with using a third table. In MySQL, you can use identity fields to make this easier. A very simple example would be using these tables (simple versions of the tables with just names without knowing any further info):

```
CREATE TABLE a
  (
    `id` int,
    `name` varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
  )
  ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE b
  (
    `id` int,
    `name` varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
  )
  ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE c
  (
    `id` int auto_increment,
    `intable` varchar(10) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
  )
  ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Then, when you want to insert a value on either table, do (a sample inserting 'Joe' into a):

```
INSERT INTO c (`intable`) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO a (`id`, `name`)
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id, 'Joe' AS name;
```

The only reason for the intable entry in c is so you know which table it was created for. Any sort of value to insert into c can be used instead.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID` might produce unexpected behaviors in highly concurrent systems.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID has no issues whatsoever on a highly concurrent system. See the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id which states "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own." Are you thinking of SQL Server?

Comment: No you're right, I was thinking of the fact that some people use LAST_INSERT_ID()+1 to insert another value, which may fail if the id+1 is already taken.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would be bad! Don't ever do that, people!